# What is the exact algorithm for encryption and decryption with hummingbird-1 cryptography?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, block-cipher, decryption

I have really googled the entire internet but could not find a clear algorithm for hummingbird-1 cryptography.The problem emerges in the decryption module:

1. What is the initial value of state register $RS_1$, $RS_2$, $RS_3$, $RS_4$.
2. What is the initial value of LFSR?
3. Having known the encryption block cipher $Ek_1$, $Ek_2$, $Ek_3$, $Ek_4$,how can we get to $Dk_1$, $Dk_2$, $Dk_3$, $Dk_4$?

Here is a link to the Encryption and Decryption Structure:  [Encryption and Decryption Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPezN.jpg)